# Grass GIS: g.extension – Not found

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I'm having problems trying to compile (r.landscape.evol and another) on the 7.6.1 version of GRASS from the g.extension command. It does not found the file in the default repository. I am running Windows 10. It´s seems the repository does not work.

```
g.extension extension=r.landscape.evol                                          
Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons <r.landscape.evol>...
ERROR: Extension <r.landscape.evol> not found
```

Comment: See here for a workaround. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328449/how-to-install-grass-add-on-after-migration-from-svn-to-github

Comment: With this workaround I was able to fixed it

Comment: We hope to come up with an update later this month. Sorry for the inconvenience.